# Why can't I pass this object correctly in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am following the tutorial from here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-symfony2-to-perform-crud-operations-on-a-vps-part-1

Here is my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $news = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('FooNewsBundle:News')
        ->findAll();
  if (!$news) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No news found');
  }

  $build['news'] = $news;
  return $this->render('FooNewsBundle:Default:news_show_all.html.twig',$build);
}
```

Here is my view for news_show_all.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
<table>
    {% for new in news %}

        <h3>{{ new.Title }}</h3>

    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

What I get is a blank page but when viewing source I get this:

```
<h3></h3>


<h3></h3>
```

Which is amazing since I have 3 items in my table and it only shows 2 and they are blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the result of \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($news); (replace the values if you like) so we know what the results consist of.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I haven't use the debug. So where do I enter \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($news);

Comment: Just use it above the return statement, it's just an equivalent of var_dump()

Comment: Just looked it up ; -) It produced nothing. Same as before.

Comment: Thats a little strange, that to me would indicate nothing is in the database. Have you got the symfony toolbar at the bottom? If not add the <html>,<head> and <body> tags to your twig file and the symfony tool bar will appear at the bottom of your page, you should then be able to go to the doctrine tool bar and click on that which will show you the query executed. You can then copy that query into your phpmyadmin or what ever your using to see what results are pulled from your database

Comment: Sorry wrong function. I also had to just use dum($news) after inserting use.

Here is output:
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#323 (5) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(26) "Foo\NewsBundle\Entity\News" ["id"]=> int(1) ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["createDate"]=> string(8) "DateTime" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#332 (5) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(26) "Foo\NewsBundle\Entity\News" ["id"]=> int(2) ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["createDate"]=> string(8) "DateTime" } }

Comment: In your PHPmyAdmin ( or your mysql database), are your fields blank?

Comment: No I checked they have 3 rows. I am using http://localhost/working/symfony/web/app_dev.php/news/ to access my bundle so no symfony info.

Comment: This line ["id"]=> int(1) ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["createDate"]=> string(8) "DateTime" says that title is blank. have you tried to replicate the query as mentioned above.

Comment: You are a rock star! Something so stupid. Had two tables News and news and I was checking News and it was using news. Okay one other question I am getting this error and I think it has to do with how I initially setup the entities. The database has column created_date and is type datetime but I get this error:
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2, t0.body AS body3, t0.create_date AS create_date4 FROM news t0':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.create_date' in 'field list'

Comment: You say created_date, the query says create_date. Your entity has a typo on the annotation I'd guess. Missing d.